# Reversing a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, reverse

I tried to reverse a list in Prolog, but i don't know how to remove the brackets `[]` during the execution.

```
inverser([],[]).
inverser(X,X).
inverser([T1|L1],[L2,T1]):- inverser(L1,L2).
```

I tried the flatten méthode but Don't know how to implémente it.

Comment: See https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=reverse/2 and its code at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#reverse/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way of reversing a list is to partition the list into its *head* and *tail*, recursively reverse the tail and append the head to it:

```
reverse( []     , [] ) .
reverse( [X|Xs] , Ys ) :- reverse(Xs,Zs), append(Zs,[X],Ys).
```

It is simple, elegant, and pure . . . and runs in O(*n*²) time. So nobody actually does that.

The simplest way to reverse a list is probably just this:

We invoke a helper predicate with an extra argument (an accumulator in this case) that we seed with the empty list. Reversing the list is as simple as prepending each item from the source list to the accumulator. This runs in O(*n*) time. Much better!

```
inverser(Xs,Ys) :- inverser(Xs,[],Ys).

inverser( []     , Ys , Ys ) .
inverser( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :- inverser(Xs,[X|Ts],Ys).
```

Note that this is not a symmetric algorithm:

| 1st Argument | 2nd Argument | Result | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[a,b,c]` | Ys | `Ys=[c,b,a]` |  |
| Xs | `[a,b,c]` | `Xs=[c,b,a]` | Backtracking goes into an infinite loop |
| `[a,b,c|Xs]` | Ys | `Xs=[], Ys=[c,b,a]` | Backtracking produces lists of every increasing length with variables as list elements |
| Xs | `[a,b,c|Ys]` | `Xs=[c,b,a], Ys=[]` | Backtracking produces lists of every increasing length with variables as list elements |
| Xs | Ys | `Xs=[], Ys=[]` | Backtracking produces lists of every increasing length with variables as list elements |

You can fix this by doing a little type checking at the outset, depending on what behavior you desire. For instance, this fails if both arguments are completely unbound and if the 1st argument is completely unbound, they are swapped so as to prevent the unbounded recursion.

```
inverser(Xs,Ys) :- var(Xs), var(Ys), !, fail.               % If both args are unbound, just fail.
inverser(Xs,Ys) :- nonvar(Xs),       !, inverser(Xs,[],Ys). % If the 1st arg is unbound, invoke the helper.
inverser(Xs,Ys) :- nonvar(Ys),          inverser(Ys,[],Xs). % If the 2nd arg is unbound, switch the order of the arguments

inverser( []     , Ys , Ys ) .
inverser( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :- inverser(Xs,[X|Ts],Ys).
```

SWI Prolog simply traverses both arguments in parallel to prevent the unbounded recursion backtracking into `inverser(Xs,[a,b,c])`.

Comment: There's no need to fail if both args are var. Also see https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/a-faster-and-still-safe-reverse/6012